# How to import a PostgreSQL table with arrays into AVRO format?

Tags: postgresql, hdfs, avro, sqoop

I have an SQL database with some columns of type `TEXT []` (array of strings).

I'm importing the database into AVRO format and saving it to HDFS using the `sqoop` command:

```
sqoop import-all-tables
    -Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true
    --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost/project
    --username postgres
    --warehouse-dir /project
    --as-avrodatafile
    --compression-codec=snappy
    --outdir output/avsc 
    --m 1
```

And getting the error:

```
23/05/08 09:33:51 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: Cannot resolve SQL type 2003
23/05/08 09:33:51 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 2003 for column genres
```

I tried to fix it by adding the `--map-column-hive 'genres'=ARRAY\<STRING\>` flag. Then `sqoop` printed this flah must be used with `--hive-import`.

The resulting command

```
sqoop import-all-tables
    -Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true
    --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost/project
    --username postgres
    --warehouse-dir /project
    --as-avrodatafile
    --compression-codec=snappy
    --outdir output/avsc 
    --m 1
    --map-column-hive 'genres'=ARRAY\<STRING\>
    --hive-import
```

is giving the error:
`Hive import is not compatible with importing into AVRO format.`

Is there a way to import SQL tables with arrays into AVRO format?

I'm using Hive 1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292